# Setting variables using getopts

Tags: bash, getopts

I would like to use getopts for parsing arguments to bash functions.

```
while getopts ${shortopts} arg; do
```

But am encountering problems in setting variable values.  Calling `myfunc -v8` or `myfunc -v 8` sets `vb` to the expected value of `8`.

```
myfunc -v 8
vb, arg:   ;  OPTARG: 8
vb: 8
```

But running the command again with `myfunc -v 21` gives

```
myfunc -v 21
vb: 1
```

Here is what I have done to handle the options

```
myfunc
{
  local vb=1

  local arg
  local shortopts="Vuhv:"

  while getopts ${shortopts} arg; do
    case ${arg} in
      # ........................................................
      ("V")
        printf "%s\n" "V01 Jul 2021 Wk27"
        return
        ;;
      ("u")
        printf "%s\n" "-V, -u, -h"
        return
        ;;
      ("h")
        printf "%s\n" "Prints status returned by getopt."
        printf "%s\n" "-V  Displays version"
        printf "%s\n" "-u  Displays usage"
        printf "%s\n" "-h  Displays help."
        printf "%s\n" "-v, -vNUM  Sets verbosity level."

        printf "%s\n" "Example: getopt-status --"
        return
        ;;
      ("v")
        vb="$OPTARG" 
        printf '%s\n' "vb, arg: $arg  ;  OPTARG: $OPTARG"
        ;;
      :)
        echo "Current argument value, OPTARG: -$OPTARG" >&2
        echo "Must supply an argument to -$OPTARG" >&2
        ;;
      ?)
        printf "%s\n" "Invalid option, OPTARG: $OPTARG"
        ;;
    esac
  done

  echo "vb: $vb"

}
```

Comment: Which shell are you using (there's no `#!` line to guide us)? How do you invoke this snippet? Is it really a function? If so, please extend the code you've given us to show a sufficient script that demontrates the problem as a complete standalone example. For example, running this as-is under `bash` generates a number of errors such as `local: can only be used in a function`. And if it is a function, why do you think `local vb=1` would allow `vb` to be accessed outside the function's scope?

Comment: I am using bash.

Comment: I tried to do that.  Futile than if you say that optional option-argument is not supported by `getopts`.  Have changed to `:`  but still encoutering the problem of setting the correct `vb`.

Comment: I have posted a complete function now.

Answer (score 1):

As ilkkachu  and others mentioned, there are a few errors there. `return` and `local` will work within a function since `return` will return an exit code of the function.

Here is a minimal example which could give you an idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

die(){ echo >&2 "$@"; exit 1; }
usage(){ echo >&2 "usage: $0 [-u] [-v num] "; exit 0; }

shortopts=":Vuhv:"
while getopts "$shortopts" opt; do
        case $opt in
        u)      usage ;;
        v)      case $OPTARG in
                ''|*[!-0-9]*) die "invalid number $OPTARG" ;;
                *) val=$OPTARG ;;
                esac
                ;;
        :)      die "argument needed to -$OPTARG" ;;
        *)      die "invalid switch -$OPTARG" ;;
        esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

echo value="$val"
```

Some notes:

> If the very first character of the option-string is a : (colon), which would normally be nonsense because there's no option letter preceding it, getopts switches to "silent error reporting mode". In productive scripts, this is usually what you want because it allows you to handle errors yourself without being disturbed by annoying messages.

For more see: https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Answer (score 1):

When using `getopts` in a function, you *must* localize `OPTARG` and especially `OPTIND`.

You can do

```bsh
myfunc() {
    local OPTIND OPTARG
    ...
```

and `getopts` will take care of initializing them.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: @Isabel [As you were told](https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2021-08/msg00052.html) on the `help-bash` mailing list, add `local OPTIND` to your function, or use `OPTIND=1`.

Comment: Should one define `OPTARG` as well, e.g. local `OPTARG`. Where should I set `OPTIND=1`?